# New file in linux environment with absolute path

Tags: java, linux, file, path, absolute

This is the problem:

1. Path to the folder we want to analyse is correctly retrieved.
2. We create the file for that folder(with the suposely AbsolutePath). Printing the AbsolutePath now adds a prefix to the original path.
3. What's in getPath is what should be in getAbsolutePath.
4. What's being added to the path is the directory where the JVM was run... The absolute path we provided is being wrongly interpreted as a relative path.
5. We can't detect the files in Ep because the file path doesn't exist.

I've tried creating using `Paths.get(string)`, `Paths.get(URI)`, `Paths.get(".").relativize(Path other)`, etc. Always with the same result.

```
logger.info("referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year): "
    + referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year)); 

File rootFolder = new File(referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year));
logger.info("rootFolder.getAbsolutePath(): " + rootFolder.getAbsolutePath());

logger.info("rootFolder.getPath(): " + rootFolder.getPath());

logger.info("System.getProperty(\"user.dir\"): " +     System.getProperty("user.dir"));

File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(filter);
```

Output:

```
referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year): /dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/dg/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/
rootFolder.getAbsolutePath(): /dvl/app/srs/tomcat/temp//dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/dg/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018
rootFolder.getPath(): /dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/dg/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018
System.getProperty("user.dir"): /dvl/app/srs/tomcat/temp
```

Comment: *Theory:* The string returned by `getYearFolder` doesn't actually start with a forward slash character, even though it looks like it does, e.g. there could be an invisible character before the `/`. Try adding `logger.info(rootFolder.getPath().startsWith("/"))` to check. If it returns false, try `logger.info(Arrays.toString(rootFolder.getPath().getBytes("UTF-8")))`  to see what's actually in the string. It should be `[47, 100, 118, 108, 47, ...]`

Comment: It's not, you're right... 
`referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year): /dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/`   `startsWith("/"): false`
`referencePattern.getLocation().getYearFolder(year).getBytes("UTF-8"): [36, 123, 115, 121, 115, 58, 117, 115, 101, 114, 46, 104, 111, 109, 101, 125, 47, 100, 97, 116, 97, 47, ...]`

Comment: How do I convert this? It seems that ${sys:user.home} is in the start of the string :/

Answer (score 0):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682276/new-file-in-linux-environment-with-absolute-path?noredirect=1#comment88396649_50682276):

> `getYearFolder(year)` writes the following to the log:
>
> `/dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/`
>
> `getYearFolder(year).getBytes("UTF-8")` writes:
>
> `[36, 123, 115, 121, 115, 58, 117, 115, 101, 114, 46, 104, 111, 109, 101, 125, 47, 100, 97, 116, 97, 47, ...]`

The bytes shown represent the string:

`${sys:user.home}/data/`

Seems that `logger.info(...)` is doing substitutions, replacing `${sys:user.home}` with `/dvl/app/srs/tomcat` **in the logged output**.

The actual value seen in Java code is `${sys:user.home}/data/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/`, which doesn't start with a `/` and is thus considered a relative path, so `getAbsolutePath()` prefixes the current directory (`/dvl/app/srs/tomcat/temp`), resulting in:

`/dvl/app/srs/tomcat/temp/${sys:user.home}/data/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/`

and then the logger performs the substitution to:

`/dvl/app/srs/tomcat/temp//dvl/app/srs/tomcat/data/ep/docs_autres/commeenne/com/2018/`

Things to consider:

- If `getYearFolder(year)` is supposed to return a file path, why is it returning `${sys:user.home}`?
- At what point (where in the code) is `${sys:user.home}` supposed to be substituted?
  It sure needs to be *before* `getAbsolutePath()` is called.
- Why is `getAbsolutePath()` called if path returned by `getYearFolder(year)` is already supposed to be absolute?

The answers to those questions should provide the guidance of how to fix the problem.